# reference specific value inside of a class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reference, calculation

i'm trying to reference *one* part of a class in order to calculate something in another part of the code. i only want to reference the dimensions, *nothing else*. below, you will see **cobra's** dimensional information is blank. i'm choosing arbitrary numbers and calculations - just trying to make it slightly "complicated" enough to explain a bit more. i hope this makes sense:

- i want **cobra's** width to equal ***viper's width divided by 2***.
- i want **cobra's** height to equal ***viper's height exactly***.
- i want to be able to ***only change viper's information and have

  cobra automatically update because it references viper***.

```css
.viper
 {
    width: calc((100px - 50px) * 3) / 2);
    height: 200px;
    font-family: garamond;
    font-color: black;

 }

.cobra
  {
    width:
    height:
    font-family: georgia;
    font-color: blue;
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this with CSS or JS?

Comment: @loomy i'm honestly not sure. i'm new to all of this. it's for a tumblr page so i edit it on replit.com and i edit the entire code on one page and it all updates automatically. i'm 90% sure it's CSS, though. this would be in the <style> section of an html code

Comment: You probably can do this just with CSS and variables but please put the basic HTML structure into your question so we can see how the two snake elements are related. Are they siblings within a parent?

Comment: @AHaworth they're two separate elements that are unrelated. i'm trying to just pull viper's information to use in cobra without having to put viper's entire calculation information into cobra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to accomplish this with JUST CSS, this can be accomplished quite easily using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

First declare your viper's `width` and `height` as a basis for a snake:

```
 :root{
  --viper-width: calc(((100px - 50px) * 3) / 2);
  --viper-height: 200px;
 }
```

Then you give this variable to the equivalent properties of your snakes that you wish to modify in relation to the viper.

```
.cobra{
  width: calc(var(--viper-width) / 2);
  height: var(--viper-height);
  font-family: georgia;
  color: blue;
}
```

Then, any time you change your `--viper-width` and `--viper-height` variables, your `.cobra` will adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS variables, but note that you have a couple of errors in your code.

font-color does not exist, use color.

The calc has a missing opening bracket.

This snippet corrects these and puts the viper height and width into the root so that these CSS variables can be used anywhere in the document (given cobra and viper are not related).

```css
:root {
  --viperW: calc(((100px - 50px) * 3) / 2);
  --viperH: 200px;
}

.viper {
  width: var(--viperW);
  height: var(--viperH);
  font-family: garamond;
  color: black;
  background-color: pink;
}

.cobra {
  width: calc(var(--viperW) / 2);
  height: var(--viperH);
  font-family: georgia;
  color: blue;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="viper">Viper</div>
<div class="cobra">Cobra</div>
```